# Python legend with GetDist tool : push a part of second line to the right while keepin the other part to the left

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, text-alignment

I use the Python `GetDist` tool available on : [GetDist tool](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

My issue is simple. I would like to push to the right a part of the second line of the legend. For the moment, I have by default the following behavior :

[image: 2 lines of legend pushed to the left]

I would like to modify the location of the partial text "`a = 300`" to the right, at the same horizontal level of first line, i.e at the same "level" than "`a = 200`" of first line, then creating a space between "Criterion taking into account" and "a = 300" : this is what I would like to get.

I have not found currently a function that could perform this or a simple option in the handling of this specification.

### Update

I tried the updated version of `@ted930511`, i.e :

```
# g.settings
g = plots.get_subplot_plotter()

# Push Fom to the right into legend
renderer = g.fig.canvas.get_renderer()
shift = max([t.get_window_extent(renderer).width for t in g.legend.get_texts()])
for t in g.legend.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    t.set_position((shift,0))
```

But it is pushed to the right too much. Here the result :

[image: Too much pushed to the right]

I have printed the value of shift : `shift = 898.1568`

Maybe this value is too large. How can I push only the part "a = xxx" to the right of legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('xx-small')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.2, 7.2/2))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8])
p1, = ax.plot([1, 2, 3], label='Opt. Flat. No Gamma. - cross - standard situation - Criterion taken into account a=200')
p2, = ax.plot([3, 2, 1], label='Pess. Flat. No Gamma. - Criterion taken into account                                            a=200')
legend = ax.legend(handles=[p1, p2], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', prop=fontP)

#renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
#shift = max([t.get_window_extent(renderer).width for t in legend.get_texts()])
#for t in legend.get_texts():
#    t.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
#    t.set_position((shift,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you have done is almost what I would like to get. I want the same second line but with the text `Pess. Flat. No Gamma - Criterion taken into account` aligned on the left (just near to orange bar) and the text `a=200` pushed on the right like your current figure : this will create a space between the 2 portions but this is the result that I would like to obtain.

Comment: thanks but isn't really a nice way to automatically place the `a=200`to the right, i.e at the same level than the first line, i.e `a=300` ?

Comment: Here is my thought: if you have many similar plots, finding automatic method is good. If only for this figure, use this as initial solution. Maybe later you will get a better solution:) Good luck. In some cases, automatic procedure means less flexibility. There is a trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have added an update concerning  your currrent solution ? If you could take a look, issue acts on too much alignment on the right for text "a = xxx". I suspect the parameter value `shift` to be too high. Regards